# Twitter API refuses my credentials

Tags: twitter

The twitter api keeps refusing my credentials, no matter what shared library I use. Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter no longer allows BASIC AUTHENTICATION on its API. You need to do OAUTH authentication. This is most likely the problem you are having. If you need further help, you need to post some code, what library you are using, and exactly what part of the API you are trying to access.